# Asp.net core 2.0 deployment huge number of dlls

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I've looked everywhere for a solution to this and could not find one.

I have a project developed in asp.net core 2.0

I was regularly publishing it and when publishing (from visual studio) the publish folder contained only the app's dlls and some dependencies.

The project is hosted on a linux box with the asp.net runtime installed so all good.

I then installed asp.net 2.1 sdk for another project and upgraded visual studio 2017 to the latest version.

Now, when I publish the asp.net core 2.0 project, I get so many additional dlls which were not included before. But, when publishing the asp.net core 2.1 project, all good. Only the project dlls and dependencies.

I'm using framework dependent deployment and the Microsoft.AspNetCore.All meta package. From what I understand, only required dlls should be included from this package and not everything.

To sum it up, I want a publish output that, given the target host contains the asp.net core 2.0 runtime alreadyu, only includes dlls that are not part of that runtime. It was working before and now it's not. How to solve this?

Appreciate any help I can get. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are publishing the application with **Self Contained** Deployment mode instead of Framework dependent. You can read more here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/

Edit the publish profile and select Framework-Dependent option

[image]

Comment: I thought that too at first but I'm not. I double checked.